# h5py accuracy for matrix storage

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, precision, h5py

I want to use Python3-h5py to store matrix to the .HDF5 format
My problem is that when I compare the initial data to the data extracted from the HDF5 file, I get surprising differences.

```
import numpy
import h5py

# Create a vector of float64 values between 0 and 1
A = numpy.array(range(16384+1))/(16384+1)

# Save the corresponding float16 array to a HDF5 file
Fid = h5py.File("Output/Test.hdf5","w")
Group01 = Fid.create_group("Group")
Group01.create_dataset("Data", data=A, dtype='f2')
# Group01.create_dataset("Data", data=A.astype(numpy.float16), dtype='f2')# Use that line to avoid the bug
Fid.flush()
Fid.close()

# Read the HDF5 file
Fid = h5py.File("Output/Test.hdf5",'r')
B = Fid["Group/Data"][:]
Fid.close()

# Compare float64 and float16 Values
print(A[8192])
print(B[8192])
print("")
print(A[8192+1])
print(B[8192+1])
print("")
print(A[16384])
print(B[16384])
```

Gives :

```
0.499969484284
0.25

0.500030515716
0.5

0.999938968569
0.5
```

Sometimes I get a difference of about "0.00003" and sometimes "0.4999".
Normally, I am supposed to always get "0.00003" which is related to the float16 rounding for a value between 0 and 1.
But the "0.4999" value is really unexpected, I have noticed that it happens to values which are close to power of 2 (for example "~1/2" will be stored as "~1/4").

Is it a bug into the h5py package ?

Thanks in advance,

Stéphane,

[Xubuntu 17.09 64bits + python3-h5py v2.7.1-2 + python3 v3.6.3-0ubuntu2]

Comment: (My first deleted comment somewhat questioned this observation. But i can reproduce it.) I think this is [relevant](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/819) to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link Sascha.

Comment: I have just changed the code to a simpler one (without the random function).

Comment: I hope it's okay, that i posted to the issue-tracker with a modification of your code. Looks like there is really something wrong. (i consider a random-based example good, if the seed is fixed and numpy's portable prng is used)

Comment: One way to avoid the bug is to do the float64 -> float16 conversion with the Python command "A = A.astype(numpy.float16)" instead of leaving the conversion with h5py.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure that this can be considered as an answer, but I finally get rid of my problem with a small circumvent.

To sum it up, it looks like there is a bug with "h5py v2.7.1-2"

When using h5py to store arrays, don't use such command :

```
`Group01.create_dataset("Data", data=A, dtype='f2')# Buggy command`
```

But instead :

```
`Group01.create_dataset("Data", data=A.astype(numpy.float16), dtype='f2')`
```

**Edit 18 Nov 2022 : with h5py==3.7.0 the bug is now fixed**